# How to get current document size in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get the current document size of a page in angular2. With jquery I made this

```
$(document).width()
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following line of code will do the work:

```
document.body.clientWidth;
```